# I'm making a discord bot, its supposed to collect scores from people, but it is sending multiple messages at once

Tags: python, discord, bots

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNQTa.png

The Code is here ^^^

I'm making a discord bot, its supposed to collect scores from people and store them in a text file to retrieve them later, I don't know why, after you message !tournament, the bot asks: How many goals for Conner?: then you type in the number, after you do that, the bot should ask How many goals for Ewan, which it does but then it asks the goals for Jack, Then Thomas, without the user giving any input, so how do I make it so the next message appears once you give the input?

Comment: Why did you not include the code as text in the question?

Comment: Look into `wait_for`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you're not stopping the code from doing the options above it.

When it is looking for Jack, `tournament` is `True` so it will also talk about Conner.

Here is some code that should work, instead.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("Received message")

    global tournament, scoreset1, scoreset2

    if message.content.startswith("!tournament") and not tournament:
        tournament = True
        await message.channel.send("Goals for Conner:")
    elif message.content.isdigit():
        if tournament and not scoreset1:
            scoreset1 = True
            await message.channel.send("Goals for Ewan:")
        elif scoreset1 and not scoreset2:
            scoreset2 = True
            await message.channel.send("Goals for Jack:")
        elif scoreset2:
            await message.channel.send("Goals for Thomas:")
```